# Trying to broadcast message with LUA on raspberry

Tags: sockets, lua, raspberry-pi, udp, broadcast

I am trying to broadcast a simple message from my raspberry to the entire network on port 6000 with the following simple code but it doesn't seem to allow the address 192.168.1.255 any other address will work.

```
local socket = require("socket")
  
local udp = assert(socket.udp())
udp:setoption('broadcast', true)
udp:settimeout(3)

assert(udp:sendto("Howdy\n", '192.168.1.255', 6000))
```

The IP on the PI is 192.168.1.127 for testing purposes but later on will be 192.168.1.1
Assert always gives me permission denied with the code above.

Comment: How do you know it isn't *"allowed"*? Is there an error message? Did you try as `root`? Did you try broadcasting to address `255.255.255.255`? What is your subnet mask?

Comment: Yes to all that, i got an error message from assert saying permission denied, and i tried 255.255.255.255 with the exact same result.

Comment: And you ran this with `sudo`?

Comment: You didn't say what your subnet mask is?

Comment: Its a normal house network, so 255.255.255.0 subnet mask, IP 192.168.1.127, i also tried it with sudo same result.